# How to round a decimal number to nearest 5 or nearest 10 in php

Tags: php, php4

How to round a decimal number to nearest 5 or nearest 10 in php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$new = round($num / 10, 0) * 10`
rounds to nearest 10

Comment: If this is an optimal solution for your problem please flag the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the special case of nearest 10, you can use a [negative precision](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php):

```
$new = round($num, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 2, round to the nearest 10 (see pascal's answer), then divide by 2. Avoid dividing/multiplying by 5 to do this since float representation will interfere with the accuracy of your results.